# How to delete extra records from my destination table while pulling the data from sql database?

Tags: ssis

I have to pull data from a SQL database table to my DB2 table. If records already exist UPDATE, for new records INSERT, for extra records in destination table DELETE those extra records. Destination table looks exactly like source table. For INSERT/UPDATE I am fine, how do I do DELETE from dest table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 has a MERGE command. This allows you to write a single SQL statement to do an INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE based on conditions you define. It is a very clean way of doing this.

So what you will do is add an "Execute SQL Task" element to your SSIS package, and add the DB2 merge statement to the task.

See this link (at the bottom are examples) - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0010873.htm

Comment: No problem, please "Mark as answer" if my suggestion ends up working for you. And don't mind coming back to ask followup questions :)

Answer (score 1):

if all you want is a copy of the source table... then avoid complexity and delete the target entirely first - then everything is just an insert.

Comment: Thanks Randy for quick response. Here is the situation. I can't delete target. I just have to do it through SSIS. I have a situation where I have to pull data when PK.column=4; In toatl I have to populate 2 tables.